# Safari/Chrome white-space:nowrap text over run

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, word-wrap

I have text without spaces and in it I want to have span with text with spaces. I want that span to be compact or uncut. I.e. when it is not completly visible it must be on next line.

I have this sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ysdWb/

```
<div id="url" contenteditable="true">SomeLongTextWithoutWhiteSpace/ItMightBeForExampleURL<span class = "bubble" contenteditable="false">Text in bubble<img src="http://www.mp.bastrnak.cz/icon/icq.png" /></span>ContinueOfSomeLongTextWithoutWhiteSpace/<span class = "bubble" contenteditable="false">Text in bubble<img src="http://www.mp.bastrnak.cz/icon/icq.png" /></span>/ItMightBeForExampleURL</div>
```

I use white-space:nowrap; and word-wrap:break-word; in my css.

(Try to change boundaries of page or change text to see how "bubbles" goes off the screen)
This code in fiddle works fine in Firefox. Is there any solution for Chrome and Safari to do the same?
Thanks for help.

Comment: with `white-space:normal;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not 100% sure I've understood the effect you are looking for, but is this it?

I've added `display:inline-block` to the `.bubble` class, and I haven't been able to get the bubbles to disappear off the side of the screen when I resize the window in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/ysdWb/6/

Comment: .bubble gets thicker. But at least some step forward.

Comment: Well, this one seems closer - I've set the line-height to 1em as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ysdWb/8/